# Mailbox Program Java (flipping booleans)

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I'm tasked with creating a program where the user enters a number, and that will be the total number of mailboxes. All the mailboxes will start in a closed position (boolean true). Then you will flip every other mailbox, then third then fourth then fifth and so on until you get to the last mailbox being the only one flipped. Then you must report back which mailboxes remain closed. I haven't got to return to the user the closed boxes yet. As I am stuck on how to get it to filter through the array.

```
    scanner  input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program will close and open mailboxes in a fixed pattern.  How many mailboxes would you like to see?");
    int numOfBoxes = input.nextInt();
    boolean [] boxes = new boolean [numOfBoxes];
    for(int i = 0; i <= numOfBoxes; i++){
      for(int j = 2; j <= numOfBoxes; j++){
        if(boxes.indexOf[i] % j == 0){
           boxes[i] = !boxes[i];
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Give an example input and output or clarify task, please.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
for(int i=2; i<=numOfBoxes; ++i) {
    for(int j=i-1; j<numOfBoxes; j+=i) {
        boxes[j] = !boxes[j]
    }
}
```

Does that do what you want?

---

**Edit**

Here's a full working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOfBoxes = 5;
    boolean [] boxes = new boolean [numOfBoxes];
    for(int i = 2; i <= numOfBoxes; ++i){
      for(int j = i-1; j < numOfBoxes; j+=i){
        boxes[j] = !boxes[j];
      }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boxes));
}
```

Running gives me the following output:

```
[false, true, true, false, true]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not correct. When 5 is given it should return: 1, 4. The code you gave gives: 1,2,4